# Is there any way to replace some part of code in Github repository dynamically?

Tags: github

I have a simple code on my Github repository that I want to make it changeable on the fly!

for example it's my code:

```
var name = "Reza";
alert("Hello " + name + "!");
```

my code is javascript and it will show an alert to the user Like "Hello Reza!" here.
I want to give some access to everyone to be able to change my code parameters before doing clone.

for example in my current code, I need to do something like this:

```
var name = {{your_name}};
alert("Hello " + name + "!");
```

And other users, should pass their name when they are sending their request to clone my project; then they will get cloned code customized by their name.

I want to know is there any way to do this using Github repository?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Why would you expect a version control system to provide this feature?

Comment: Most of code need customization to work, and what is the goal of github? to just save our file on their servers? it's not big expect that one of the most famous version control system doing support for something this much simple and useful for all of developers!

Comment: @RezaAmya, expanding variables in source code during cloning would be a pretty strange way of customizing source code. You can always load data from environment variables or untracked configuration files, building "compiled" versions using those configuration values if you want. But that's not _Git_'s responsibility.

Comment: @Chris it's a simple scenario: I have a Powershell code that will build a resource group, azure storage account and two Virtual Machine, that all of those things, will build entirely automatically. then everyone that have an Azure Account, just need to set his username and password and stay back and wait to finish the progress. In the following, I will try to use Github, to deploy so many other projects inside the VMs automatically, but in some cases, I need to set some configuration. for example I need to set the VM's IP address. I can download it, Unzip! and change manually, or even by code

Comment: @Chris but downloading and unzipping the code from the Github repository to a temporary directory and changing manually or even by hard coding, to something else, is more stranger than what I am searching for. we are always clone from github by a URL, why it is this much strange to pass some parameters to that URL and have a re-compiled code?

Comment: "Why it is this much strange to pass some parameters to that URL and have a re-compiled code?" Because that's _not what Git **does**_. There are tons of ways of doing something like you're asking for. It's a bit dated these days, but check out https://puphpet.com/ for an example web application that (I think) does something very similar to what you're trying to do. Note that it's not a bunch of files sitting on GitHub, it's an _application_ that users can use to generate the Vagrant configuration they desire. You're free to build something similar for your use case.